# PDO drivers no value in Windows PC

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to practice the PDO and mysqli usage on my PC with Windows 10, and PHP 7.4.7
After getting the "could not find driver" error, I used phpinfo() to see that Configuration File (php.ini) Path was C:\WINDOWS. I copied the php.ini-production file and changed its name to php.ini (there was no php.ini file initially), and then I changed the extension_dir from felative to the path to ext folder. I uncommented the extensions I need, and tried again. Right now the php_pdo_mysql.dll file can be found in the ext folder, but phpinfo() does not show any drivers, and the error is still present. Is there anything else I should edit?

Comment: Maybe you should install WAMPServer or XAMPP and then all the config will be done for you.

Comment: Extensions need to be included in the php.ini file or their includes. Have a look in it, maybe it is just commented out. Remove the `;` at the line beginning to make it active.

Comment: I've never seen `php.ini` located at `C:\WINDOWS`. What path does "Loaded Configuration File" (the line below that) show?

Comment: you need to restart the web server